# Draw QPainterPath zoomed in/out and without inside outlines

Tags: c++, qt, path, zooming, qpainter

I'm working on an image editor in Qt, and I'm attempting to implement the selection tool. I'm planning on using a QPainterPath path to clip the drawing area.

What I'm having trouble with is drawing the path so the user can see what's selected. I can use QPainter::drawPath, but when I zoom in, it is unclear exactly which pixels are selected. In addition, the outline is drawn even inside selected pixels.

What I want (screenshot from Paint.NET)
[image]

What I'm getting now (using transformations)
[image]

The only way I can think of fixing this is iterating through every point in the picture and using QPainterPath::contains to construct a new, zoomed-in path that has rough edges and no inside outlines, but that's horribly inefficient.

EDIT:
If there's some simple way to outline an image, I could draw the selection without antialiasing on a separate image, stretch it, add an outline, and then draw it over the image, but I can't find any way to outline an image.

Comment: Do you also scale the QPainter when drawing the selection outline? It looks like you zoom the image, but do not apply the same zoom factor on the outline too.

Comment: The two images I've shown above don't have the same area selected.